# Error in sending mail with flask_mail and gmail in aws

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, gmail, flask-mail

I'm trying to send an email using flask_email and gmail.
when I run it locally on my laptop its working, but when i create the docker image and run it on aws i get the error in the image

```
# Configuration for Flask-Mail
app.config["MAIL_SERVER"] = "smtp.gmail.com"
app.config["MAIL_PORT"] = 465
app.config["MAIL_USE_TLS"] = False
app.config["MAIL_USE_SSL"] = True
app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"] = username
app.config["MAIL_PASSWORD"] = password
app.config["MAIL_DEBUG"] = True
```

The Error:

```html
ERROR:app:Exception on /api/mail/sendMail [POST]                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  File "/app/routes/mail_routes.py", line 49, in send_email                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    mail.send(msg)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 491, in send                                                                                                                                                                              
    with self.connect() as connection:                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 144, in __enter__                                                                                                                                                                         
    self.host = self.configure_host()                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 156, in configure_host                                                                                                                                                                    
    host = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(self.mail.server, self.mail.port)                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 1048, in __init__                                                                                                                                                                                          
    SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout,                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__                                                                                                                                                                                           
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 339, in connect                                                                                                                                                                                            
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 1054, in _get_socket                                                                                                                                                                                       
    new_socket = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,                                                                                                                                                                                              
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection                                                                                                                                                                                   
    raise err                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection                                                                                                                                                                                   
    sock.connect(sa)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

i tried changing the ports connecting to the smtp server

Comment: Do not use Flask-Mail. It is dead. Its last update was almost TEN YEARS ago and the author deleted the source repo. And generally, Gmail is not a good option if you want to send emails from a webapp - it's an email service for end users after all.

Comment: tried using smtplib and still not working